# jsp List populate into javascript array

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'am trying to pass Spring JavaList over jsp-list to javascript array.

My code:

```
<c:set var = "currentcars" scope = "session" value = "${cars}"/>
```

Now I want populate content from "currentcars" within jsp into javascript-array, but I am not so familiar with jsp-syntax.

Within jsp:

```
<script ....>
    var carsArray = new Array();
</script>   

<c:forEach items="currentcars" var="car">

    //pseudocode:
    carsArray.push(<c:out value="${car}"/>);

<c:forEach>
```

How could I do that?

Comment: What is 'car'? A primitive value (e.g. `String`), or an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script tag you can do something like this(car is not primitive type):

```
    var carsArray = new Array();
    <c:forEach items="currentcars" var="car">
        c = new Object();
//name property example
        c.name= '${car.name}'; 
//other properties

        carsArray.push(c);
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: can i access on java-script variable "carsArray" within jsp-code without <script>- tag? by the line: carsArray.push(c);

Comment: You should think what html code you got after jsp got compiled, we are generating js code then it should be on script tag..